# Efficiently applying conditions to a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, apply, do.call

I have an `integer` `matrix`:

```
set.seed(1)
counts.mat <- matrix(sample(50,29*10,replace=T),nrow=10,ncol=29)
colnames(counts.mat) <- c("ww.1m_1","ww.1m_2","wm.1m_1","wm.1m_2","wm.1m_3","wn.1m_1","wn.1m_2",
"A_1","A_2","B_1","B_2","C_1","C_2",
"ww.2m_1","ww.2m_2","ww.2m_3","wm.2m_1","wm.2m_2","wn.2m_1","wn.2m_2",
"ww.3m_1","ww.3m_2","ww.3m_3","wm.3m_1","wm.3m_2","wm.3m_3","wn.3m_1","wn.3m_2","wn.3m_3")
```

Its elements represent counts of a certain measurement taken from a set of experiments (in this example 3) which are described in this `list` of `data.frame`'s:

```
df.list <- list(df1 = data.frame(gt1=c("ww.1m","wm.1m","wn.1m"),kt1=c("A","B","C"),stringsAsFactors=F),
                df2 = data.frame(gt2=c("ww.2m","wm.2m","wn.2m"),stringsAsFactors=F),
                df3 = data.frame(gt2=c("ww.3m","wm.3m","wn.3m"),stringsAsFactors=F))
```

The columns in every `data.frame` in `df.list` are the factors of its corresponding experiment and the values of that columns are the factor levels. The `colnames` of `counts.mat` are the replicates of these factor levels, and their names follow this format:

`<factor.level>_<replicate>`.

This corresponds them to `df.list`.

For example, `gt1` in `df.list$df1` is a factor with levels:

`"ww.1m" "wm.1m" "wn.1m"`

whose respective replicates in `counts.mat` are:

`"ww.1m_1","ww.1m_2","wm.1m_1","wm.1m_2","wm.1m_3","wn.1m_1","wn.1m_2"`

Given:

`min.replicates <- 1`

`min.counts <- 10`

what I want to do is for each factor (column),  in each `data.frame` in `df.list` return `TRUE` or `FALSE` if at least `min.replicates` or more have at least `min.counts` or more for each row in `counts.mat`.

The result should be a `matrix` where its number of columns equals the total number of factor levels of `df.list` and number of rows is equal to the number of rows of `counts.mat`.

Here's what I think is a slow implementation:

```
res.mat <- do.call(rbind,lapply(1:nrow(counts.mat),function(i){
  return(do.call(cbind,lapply(1:length(df.list),function(l){
    return(do.call(cbind,lapply(1:ncol(df.list[[l]]),function(j){
      return(do.call(cbind,lapply(1:nrow(df.list[[l]]),function(k){
        return(length(which(counts.mat[i,which(grepl(paste0(df.list[[l]][k,j],"_\\d+$"),colnames(counts.mat),perl=T))] >= min.counts)) >= min.replicates)
        })))
      })))
    })))
}))
```

So I'm looking for something significantly faster.

Comment: In your `counts.mat` you have duplicate column names `wm.3m_1` and `wm.3m_2` - should those on the penultimate line be `2m` rather than `3m`?

Comment: Sorry about that - fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does the same thing, and should be faster...

```
dfcols <- unlist(df.list) #extract list of columns required as a vector
matcols <- lapply(dfcols,function(x) which(startsWith(colnames(counts.mat),x))) #match to matrix columns
resmat <- sapply(1:length(dfcols),function(i) 
        apply(counts.mat[,matcols[[i]]],1,function(y) sum(y>=min.count) >= min.replicates))
colnames(resmat) <- dfcols #set colnames in output
```

With the correction in my comment above, and `min.replicates` set to 30 (all elements are `TRUE` if it is 10, with your example), this gives...

```
resmat
      ww.1m wm.1m wn.1m     A     B     C ww.2m wm.2m wn.2m ww.3m wm.3m wn.3m
 [1,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
 [2,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
 [3,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [4,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [5,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
 [6,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
 [7,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
 [8,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
 [9,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[10,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```